# Have a Django project that uses Pinax and templates say "load bootstrap." But where is it?

Tags: django, pinax

I have a legacy Django project that I know uses "Pinax," and I see templates that say `{%load bootstrap%}` but ... where is that to be found?  (That is to say, "today?")  `bootstrap3?`  If so, exactly what am I up against to keep this thing working?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like that project uses pinax-theme-bootstrap. Per the README dependencies section, it was last tested with Bootstrap 3.3.5. pinax-theme-bootstrap was eventually replaced with pinax-templates, also found in the Pinax GitHub organization. https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap